# Why Statements after kotlin's MutableStateFlow collect methods are unreachable?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

```
var hotFlow = MutableStateFlow("John")
lifecycleScope.launch{
            hotFlow.collect {
                println("Value Of Data $it")
            }
            println("Hello UnReachable")
        }
```

I'm expecting when code initialization takes place or when I update the value of `MutableStateFlow`, `println()` should print above written statements, but it is not printed and also lint compiler shows that particular `println()` statement is unreachable, why is that so?..

Comment: What would be your expected behavior? When exactly and why the collecting would complete, allowing to go to the next line?

Comment: Yes , i'm just experimenting with codeflow , i found it strange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `collect` on a `SharedFlow` never returns. The Kotlin compiler is smart about that, and sees the `Nothing` return type. So it knows that call can't complete normally, and all statements below it are unreachable.

See [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/collect.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks @Jorn , got it , can u bit explain more why the behaviour of StateFlow is such ?..

Comment: In the case of a MutableStateFlow, it's always possible another value could be emitted, so it can never be considered complete. In the case of a StateFlow created from `stateIn`, it's an unfortunate implementation side effect of how upstream errors are handled. I don't understand exactly the reason that creates this restriction.